# Centralizing constants on a Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, interface, constants

In a project, I often need to work constants and I never in support of doing them hardcode like

```
if (status === 2) { // do something }
```

So, I need to centralize these constants so that I can give them a readable name like STATUS_SUCCESS and use the constant across the project.

My first question is, what is the best approach to make, place and use them across a laravel project?

I see people create an Enums folder inside app and make relevant interface inside.

```
interface Ticket {
  const STATUS_OPEN = 1;
}

//Use like
if (status === Ticket::STATUS_OPEN) {// do something}
```

And, second question is, how effective and relevant this enum approach and why?
Thank you.

Comment: If they mean different things to different models, they shouldn't be shared. In your example of user status and ticket status, `1` can mean `inactive` or `open` - unless you're going to call it `STATUS_INACTIVE_OR_OPEN_OR_MAYBE_SOME_OTHER_THING` it doesn't make sense to use the same constant for both.

Comment: it depends on the type of variable, if they are static ones then you can manage using configuration, you can use view composer if you want to share variables among views.

Comment: @ceejayoz they mean the same everywhere. Sorry, I mistakenly used two different number for same thing. now edited.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you should create a file named **constants.php** in `config` folder and define your constants there and use them throughout your application using config. Contents of the file will be

```
return [
    'options' => [
        'option_attachment' => '13',
        'option_email' => '14',
        'option_monetery' => '15',
        'option_ratings' => '16',
        'option_textarea' => '17',
    ]
];
```

and access them using the following code

```
Config::get('constants.options');
// or if you want a specific one
Config::get('constants.options.option_attachment');
```

for simplicity, don't make nested arrays of constants.

Then I think the best way is to create  a class with constants

```
class Constant
{
    const DRAFT = 1;
    const PUBLISHED = 2;
    const DELETED = 3;
}
```

You would use:

```
echo Constant::DRAFT;
```

Comment: The reason I don't prefer config is, it makes the statement long and unclean.
Like,

    config::get('options.option_email') // so long